# Ubuntu spying in Empathy? why closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Once the question was closed
But why closed ?

This is a very important question!

To work Empathy Ubuntu asks permission to collect information about me.
Why when I do not wish to collect information about me by Ubuntu, Empathy does not work!

In Fedora or OpenSuse, Mageia Empathy works without such a request.

Comment: You need to add more information to your question, that's why it was closed, please keep editing your existing question with more information. thanks!

Comment: Probably adding a screenshot or something to what you mean by "asks for permission" would help people understand the question.

Comment: @JorgeCastro how you came out to the conclusion that that was what the user wanted to ask beats me... Kudos for that, superb.

Comment: Sorry I closed your question without an explain, the comments from Jorge should be enough for you to know why it was closed. Better wording and some more information are always vital to posts.

Comment: @Bruno I blew away my empathy settings and ran it first-run and the window popped up asking for approval to access my google account for gtalk.

Comment: :) you wont properly know anything about tech until you abuse it till it breaks.

Answer (score 3):

The [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291695/why-does-empathy-ask-for-permission-to-access-my-remote-accounts#question) was very [strangely worded](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/291695/1) and as written, the reviewers probably thought it to be argumentative or not a reasonable question that could have been answered.

However, super-bot Jorge got the gist of the underlying premise and has edited it.

This is now much more of a ready Q&A style question and hence has been reopened.

Comment: That's right a little too direct, I wrote the quastion first time Sorry